# List categories and their posts from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types, taxonomy

I want to show the categories and their posts. (custom post type)

**It should look like this:**

Category 1

- Post A (has cat. 1)
- Post B (has cat. 1)

Category 2

- Post X (has cat. 2)
- Post Y (has cat. 2)

**At the moment I get following output:**

Category 1

- Post A (in cat. 1)
- Post B (in cat. 1)
- Post X (in cat. 2)
- Post Y (in cat. 2)

Category 2

- Post A (in cat. 1)
- Post B (in cat. 1)
- Post X (in cat. 2)
- Post Y (in cat. 2)

**Heres my code: functions.php**

```
... 
register_taxonomy(
    'aundo-cat',
    'cdh_aundo',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Kategorien A und O',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
        )
    );
...


add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'cdh_aundo',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'A und O' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'A und O' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-heart',
        'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'a-und-o-der-unternehmenskommunikation'),
        'supports' => array (
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'category',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions' )
        )
    );
}
```

**Code in template file:**

```
<?php
$cat_args = array (
'taxonomy' => 'aundo-cat',
);
$categories = get_categories ( $cat_args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
$cat_query = null;
$args = array (
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'cdh_aundo',
    'taxonomy' => 'aundo-cat'
    );

$cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo "<h3>". $category->name ."</h3>";
    echo "<ul>";
    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
        $cat_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php if( get_field('aundo_tipp_nummer') ): ?>
                <div class="">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! What is your issue for helping you ?

Comment: Thank you :). The issue is above. I get the categories with posts but it shows me all posts and not only the posts in the specific cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$cat_args = array (
    'taxonomy' => 'aundo-cat',
);
$categories = get_categories ( $cat_args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $cat_query = null;
    $args = array (
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'cdh_aundo',
        'taxonomy' => 'aundo-cat',
        'term' => $category->slug
    );

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo "<h3>". $category->name ."</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
            $cat_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php if( get_field('aundo_tipp_nummer') ): ?>
                    <div class="">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

i just added this: `'term' => $category->slug`

Comment: Thank you so much! That's it!

Answer (score 2):

> You can try by this way

```
<?php
    $cat = get_terms('category');
    foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
        echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>';
        $postArg = array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=>-1,'order'=>'desc',
                          'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                    'field' => 'term_id',
                                                    'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                )
                        ));

        $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
        global $post;

        if($getPost->have_posts()){
            echo '<ul>';
                while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                    echo "<li>".$post->post_title."</li>";
                endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
        }

    }
?>
```

[image]