# WordPress displaying CPT filtered by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am displaying all posts from a custom post type but I would like to display them ordered by taxonomy.

I want it to look like this:

Term 1:

> - post x
> - post y

Term 2:

> - post z
>
> Term 3:
>
> - post n

My plan is to make 3 wp_queries each for every taxonomy since I have 3 but I have some troubles setting up my query.

This is what my query looks like:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'job',
        'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'slug',
                    ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    ));
```

Making 3 queries seems a bit dumb, is there a better way to do this with maybe 1 query?

Comment: you get no error ... Go to your wp-config.php file and active the debug mode for see the errors :)

Comment: @Xenofexs I've done this and I still get no error and I am 100% sure there are posts with 'sales'

Comment: @Xenofexs I guess I formulated my question wrong my main questions is there an easier way than to work with 3 querries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can do by this way also.

```
 <?php

     $cat = get_terms('category'); // you can put your custom taxonomy name as place of category.
        foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
            echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>';
            $postArg = array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=>-1,'order'=>'desc',
                              'tax_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                        'field' => 'term_id',
                                                        'terms' => $catVal->term_id
                                                    )
                            ));

            $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
            global $post;

            if($getPost->have_posts()){
                echo '<ul>';
                    while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();
                        echo "<li>".$post->post_title."</li>";
                    endwhile;
                echo '</ul>';
            }

        }
    ?>
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot friend

Comment: Hum, but you do 3 queries, no ?

Comment: No i did not  by using 3 queries no , i have already reply same question.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418102/list-categories-and-their-posts-from-custom-post-type/36423378#36423378

Answer (score 0):

You can select more taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

After that, you need to parse one time your result for make an array like you want.

And you loop on this array after for display the informations

Or you can (but I dont like this way) store your html in php var

Ex 1 :

```
<?php 
      while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post(); ?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php
             endwhile;
             wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>


    $jobList = array();


    $posts = $posts->get_posts();

    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        $jobList[$post['yourTaxFieldName']][] = $post;
    }
    // and you can now loop on $jobList for display in order your jobs categories
```

Ex 2 : (bad work but it's work)

```
$job1 = '';
$job2 = '';
$job3 = '';

while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();
    if($yourTaxFieldName == 1)
        $job1 .= '<li>'.$your_content.'</li>';
    elseif ($yourTaxFieldName == 2) 
    {
        $job2 .= '<li>'.$your_content.'</li>';
    }
    else {
        $job3 .= '<li>'.$your_content.'</li>';
    }
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();

echo '<ul><h1>First job : </h1> ',$job1,' </ul>'; 
// etc.
```